# solving binary linear equation in matlab

Tags: matlab, binary

Consider a binary linear equation of form `x*A = b`. I want to solve for **x**, the efficiency way is by avoiding using `x = b*inv(A)` and instead using `x= b/A`.But with this command results are not in binary form. I tried the command `x = mod(b/A ,2)`but still result was not in binary. How to fix this?

example
`

```
x = 1     0     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     0`
```

and matrix A is

```
`0     1     0     1     0     0     1     1     1     1
 0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     1
 0     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     1     1
 1     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
 0     1     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     0
 0     0     1     1     0     0     0     1     0     0
 1     1     1     1     0     1     0     1     1     1
 1     0     1     0     1     1     1     0     1     1
 1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     0`

which is full rank.
```

then

```
>> b = mod (x*A,2)
```

b =

```
 1     0     1     1     1     0     1     0     1     1
```

To find `x`, am getting

```
>> k = b / A
```

k =

Columns 1 through 6

```
1.3750   -0.5000   -0.7500   -0.7500    0.8750   -0.5000
```

Columns 7 through 10

```
1.8750   -0.5000    2.1250   -0.7500
```

or if am using modulus 2, the result is

```
>> k = mod (b / A,2)
```

k =

Columns 1 through 6

```
1.3750    1.5000    1.2500    1.2500    0.8750    1.5000
```

Columns 7 through 10

```
1.8750    1.5000    0.1250    1.2500
```

So ,how can I get `x` in the same binary form? and by the way matrices are all in **class double** not **galois field**

Comment: Sizes of `A` and `b`? Fields on which their values are defined? Ideally give an example of input data and desired result

Comment: What do you mean by "binary" ? I hope you're not entering values like `10110` and hoping that various functions automagically recognize that as a binary number!

Comment: The matrix `A` in your example is 10x10 with nonzero determinant. So there is only one solution to the system __xA__ = __b__ , and it's `b/A`. in general, there is no `b` made up of zeros and ones that will solve your system

Comment: @Luis Mendo I updated my question, in original problem the size of `À` is **602*602** and `b`'s is **1*602**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve`x`in binary form, matrix **A** should be in galois field.
consider the following example;

```
>> x = randi ([0 1],1,10)
```

x =

```
 1     1     0     1     1     1     0     1     1     1

>> A = gf (randi([0 1],10,10))
```

A = GF(2) array.

Array elements =

Columns 1 through 6

```
       1           1           1           0           0           1
       1           0           1           0           1           0
       1           0           1           1           0           1
       0           0           0           0           0           1
       1           1           1           0           1           1
       0           1           0           1           0           1
       0           0           0           1           1           1
       0           1           0           0           1           0
       0           0           1           0           1           0
       0           0           1           0           0           1
```

Columns 7 through 10

```
       1           1           0           0
       1           0           1           1
       1           1           0           0
       0           0           1           0
       1           1           1           1
       0           1           1           1
       1           0           1           0
       1           1           1           0
       1           0           0           0
       1           1           1           0
```

then,

```
>> b = x*A
```

b = GF(2) array.

Array elements =

Columns 1 through 6

```
       1           0           1           1           0           1
```

Columns 7 through 10

```
       0           1           0           1

>> x_solved = b*inv (A)
```

x_solved = GF(2) array.

Array elements =

Columns 1 through 6

```
       1           1           0           1           1           1
```

Columns 7 through 10

```
       0           1           1           1
```

As you can see **x_solved** is the same as the original **x**. Therefore you should convert matrix `A` to galois field by just running a code`A = gf(A)`.

Answer (score 2):

This example at [Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/16192-inversion-of-a-boolean-matrix) shows how to perform boolean matrix inversion with MATLAB and I believe answers your question.

I have not quite gotten it working perfectly, but I believe you need to use a combination of `mod()` and `logical()` for example:

```
A=logical(A);
b=(mod(x*A,2));
inverseA= ~A;
k=mod(b*inverseA,2)
```

this gives

```
k=[1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0]
```

which is not x, but i think if you play around with the `logical` function and logical operations in conjunction with `mod()` you should be able to get it to work

Comment: even with command `double()` results are not in binary.`                      >> k = mod (double(x)/double(A),2)

k =

  Columns 1 through 6

    1.0000         0         0    1.5000    1.5000    0.5000

  Columns 7 through 10

         0    0.5000    1.5000    0.5000
`

Comment: thanks for the feedback @Engtyma. I edited my answer per your feedback. By making either A, x, or b a logical array, you confine it to containing only 0's and 1's. Hopefully the updated answer can guide you in the right direction